# outlook cannot attach files on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I am not able to attach files with my owa(outlook).

When I click on the attach file icon in the New message, nothing happens. A new window with browse option does not appear where I can attach the files. Any help in this regard would be appreciated. This has bothered me for a long time and is now affecting my work. Hope to hear from you guys soon.

PS. I am using firefox

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: I tried with chromium and it works fine with it, although I don't use chromium much

Comment: It can be due to some user settings or addons preventing it. Have you tried in a "clean" Firefox? You can use the guest user session for that. If it doesn't work there then most likely the reason is Microsoft not playing ball and blocking Firefox for Linux because reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean" firefox??

Comment: The troubleshooting often is about ruling out hypotheses until a diagnostic by exclusion is reached. With that in mind, my suggestion was about ruling out something in your Firefox profile and for that the best way is to run Firefox without your user settings, addons, etc. That's the Firefox you have in the guest session.

Comment: I used the guest session and opened firefox in it and owa, but same cannot attach the files. Also in add ons I see 2 things:
Shockwave flash 11.2 r202 and 24.0 r0. 11.2 one is outdated it's written while 24.0.r0 is fine. Can that be the issue??. I already tried purging flashplugin which removed 24.0.r0 and then installed back again but nothing happened

Comment: No, nothing to do with Flash. The second hypotheses, *most likely the reason is Microsoft not playing ball and blocking Firefox for Linux because reasons* is looking more viable. Anyway, you should contact their support about it.